# Why does Webkit attach HTMLDivElements to window object?

Tags: javascript, webkit

I used to be checking for the presence of globally available JS libraries by checking the content of the `window` object. Now I am thrown back by the fact that if I check for say jQuery and have an element like this: `<div id="jQuery">` on the page, it will be available under `window.jQuery`.

**How is this a good thing?**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xVeJ/2/

Am on Chrome 16.0.912.75 on Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, that's because named elements were exposed as properties of the `document` object in early versions of the DOM interface. Then some browsers decided to also expose these properties on the `window` object. See bobince's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/464709) for the full story.

To work around this situation, you can test that `window.jQuery` is a function:

```
if (typeof window.jQuery === "function") {
    // jQuery should be available.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your and bobince's answer Frédéric.